# Push only modified line in File

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, gitlab, versioning

recently, i've learned how to add my solution to a Source Control. afterwards i've connected it to my GitLab Account.

for a single developer, i basically know how things work, from committing locally to pushing it to the server to reflect and merge the changes to the online repository.

but i was wondering how would this happen if, for example i'm on a team, three members let's say. all three of use working on a single solution but with our own copies on our own laptops

is it possible to only merge the modified line to the server. i'm experiencing conflicts on merging to the server

like for example, i've added 3 lines and i've committed the changes to the server, then after my team mate had 5 lines, my version is overwritten instead of them being merged together.

am i missing something ?. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good practice is to **always pull any changes down from the remote** *before pushing*.  This would allow the user to get any changes that you've made and incorporate theirs as well.

The merge conflict is the expected result as both you and your partner have modified the same lines, and is precisely what you would need in order to not overwrite each others changes.  You would just need to resolve the merge conflict before pushing.  The only time that you would overwrite each others changes is if you discard the other persons changes and accept your changes when resolving the merge.

There are a number of merge tools you could use like [kdiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), [diffmerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) etc. that would help you select which lines to add so that you are not overwriting each others changes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's stick to the git terminology: you can `merge` branches and `push` or `fetch` them to/from server (`remote`).

So if you experiencing conflicts on *pushing* to the remome, then you have to `fetch` changes from the remote, `merge` them locally and `push` back to the origin (remote) your commit and, almost always, the "merge commit".

Concerning your question in the header:

> Push only modified line in File

Yes, it is possible to `stage` and `commit` only one `hunk`(few lines of code) instead of all file. See `git add -p`. Or if you prefer GUI interface, as far as I remember, the official client for github supports commit by hunks.

Comment: well currently, we're on a single branch (master). assuming that there are 3 members on my team, all of use merge on the single same branch (that of which is the master). sorry but i am new to git repos, but is it a bad practice to have a single branch for all members ? theoretically, we all have individual branches in a single repo ?.

Comment: @TheQuestioner " theoretically, we all have individual branches in a single repo ?" - actually, you have 4 copies of the master branch: for every developer and one at the origin/remote. This origin/remote branch simplifies simultaneous work on one brach. E.g, A and B made some changes on project and commited them to their local branches. Now they want to introduce the results to the other developers, so they push their commits to the remote. A pushes first and succeeds, then B pushes and get error. Now B should fetch changes (commits A) from the remote, merge locally and push to the remote.

Comment: @TheQuestioner "is it a bad practice to have a single branch for all members" - sometimes one branch is enough, but it may lead to situation when a "bad" commit (which makes project uncompilable or has some critical bugs) may block other developers, until the problem will be resolved. I advise you to create a branch for each task; Creating branches is really easy and can save a lot of time. It's also worth to spend a day for reading this [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). I believe you may find there a lot of useful techniques that will save you time in future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a little explanation, suppose the team is composed by 2 members (**A-B**) and they're coding in the same afternoon.

- A commits his changes and then pushes to remote repository;
- B commits his changes and then pushes to remote repository after A;

When B pushes, his local code is not aligned with remote repository code, since there's a new commit in the history. User B is forced to pull the new commit before pushing and eventually resolve locally a merge conflict.

Then, B can push to remote repository too and A can pull new changes made by B.

Hope i explained.

Comment: if we're coding in the same afternoon and assuming that A commits and added 50 lines to code.cs and B also has 150 new lines on code.cs, wouldn't pulling A's code to B's local overwrite the existing 150 lines and replace it with A's 50 lines ?. as per my experience, after i've modified code.cs with adding 50 lines of codes and another team member with 150 lines of code pulled my commit to the online repo, his/her 150 lines of code were overwritten with that of my 50 lines of code

Comment: When another team member with 150 lines of code pull your commit from the online repo, he must resolve the merge conflict. If he choose to accept only his changes, your code will be overwritten. But he can choose to accept your changes too and his changes will be overwritten. Or (the right approach) he has to merge manually the file using a merge tool and choose which portions of your code and which portions of his code should be mantained. Note: if team member pull from repo with stages changes, so without commit first, merge conflict could be resolved automaically and break some code.